# Selecting rows that do not match criteria of inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, one that holds lot of links (tvlinks), and another that holds list of substrings to be matched against the name of the links (tvshows):

```
tvlinks:
  id      (int 11) - primary index key
  name    (text)   - name of the tv show link
  link    (text)   - link to a website with information about the tv show

tvshows:
  id      (int 11) - primary index key
  name    (text)   - name of the tv show
  match   (text)   - substring to be matched against name in tvlinks table
```

there can be multiple rows in tvlinks with exactly the same name and different link. There is no duplicate rows.

i use the following query to get all rows from tvlinks where tvshows.match is a substring of tvlinks.name:

```
SELECT l.id,
       l.name,
       l.link
    FROM tvlinks tvl
  INNER JOIN tvshows tvs
  ON ( INSTR(tvl.name, tvs.match )
  ORDER BY tvl.name
;
```

and it works fine, my problem is that i'd like to put together another query that would return only the rows that do not get matched by the query above.

i've been bashing my head on the keyboard on and off for a week or two, and i'm sure its something really simple that i'm missing in a big way. :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: never tested but seems as jsfiddle - you  can prepare an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select id from tvlinks where id not in (select l.id,
    FROM tvlinks tvl
  INNER JOIN tvshows tvs
  ON ( INSTR(tvl.name, tvs.match )
  ORDER BY tvl.name
;)`

Not efficient per se, all depends on your tables.

Comment: Thank You, i was able to incorporate your solution into my program :)

Answer (score 0):

`INSTR()` - Return the index of the first occurrence of substring - not the condition you need

Comment: it works as he says because it will return false if substring not present.  There are better ways to do this.

Comment: it will return 0 and the correct way is to be written as `INSTR(...) > 0`

Comment: agreed - mysql evaluates 0 as false: try select * from TABLE where 0; and select * from TABLE where 1;

Comment: i used INSTR in that way because it appears to be slightly faster than writing it out 'proper' using function with `IF INSTR("string", "string") THEN RETURN 1; END IF;` in it, and running 1 mil iterations thru `benchmark` call, the `if` without the `> 0` was almost exactly 3 seconds faster on the benchmark than the other way around.